# Getting next 15 days data from current date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get next 15 days data from current date. And i have used my query like this

```
SELECT bom.bid, 
       bom.item, 
       bom.cost, 
       bom.location, 
       work_order_line_items.id, 
       work_order_line_items.item, 
       Date(work_order_line_items.required_date) AS date, 
       Sum(work_order_line_items.quantity)       AS TQTY, 
       items.item_id, 
       items.in_stock 
FROM   bom 
       INNER JOIN work_order_line_items 
               ON bom.item = work_order_line_items.item 
       INNER JOIN items 
               ON work_order_line_items.item = items.item_id 
WHERE  Date(work_order_line_items.required_date) = 
       Date_add(Curdate(), INTERVAL 15 day) 
GROUP  BY work_order_line_items.required_date
```

in required_date column i have data .. `2014-12-28`, `2014-12-31`, `2015-01-03`, `2015-01-07`

But i am not getting any result after running the query. Can somebody please suggest me where i am wrong?

Comment: `=`.... you're looking for an exact date; change to `<=`

Comment: Yeah!. Sorry. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Mark, but it is not showing `2015` data eventhough it comes in 15 days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems in this query.

First, you're using equality rather than inequality in your `WHERE` clause. So you'll only pick up dates that are exactly fifteen days in the future.

Second, your `WHERE` clause defeats the use of an index on the `required_date` column, necessitating a table scan.  If you have dozens of items in your table, this doesn't matter, but if you get tens of thousands, your performance will suffer.

A better `WHERE`  clause might be this:

```
WHERE  work_order_line_items.required_date >= CURDATE()
  AND  work_order_line_items.required_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 16 DAY
```

This will pick up all the items starting at midnight in the present day and ending just before midnight sixteen days out.  And it can do it with a range scan on an index on your `required_date` column.

Third, you are misusing the MySQL extension to GROUP BY.  You're going to get unpredictable values in your result set.   Read this.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Here's a better version of your GROUP BY clause. Notice that it mentions all the columns in your result set except the aggregated ones.

```
GROUP BY bom.bid, 
         bom.item, 
         bom.cost, 
         bom.location, 
         work_order_line_items.id, 
         work_order_line_items.item, 
         DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date), 
         items.item_id, 
         items.in_stock
```

Comment: Sir, I tried like this in my query
`SELECT bom.bid, bom.item, bom.cost, bom.location, work_order_line_items.id, work_order_line_items.item, DATE( work_order_line_items.required_date ) AS DATE, SUM( work_order_line_items.quantity ) AS TQTY, items.item_id, items.in_stock
FROM bom
INNER JOIN work_order_line_items ON bom.item = work_order_line_items.item
INNER JOIN items ON work_order_line_items.item = items.item_id
WHERE (
work_order_line_items.required_date >= CURDATE( )` But it turns out a single record. For year changing is there anything else i need to mention? please suggest

Comment: I used GROUP BY DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) and the result is right. Thank you

Comment: @user2823107, please look at the SQL documentation to understand how `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` work together. `SUM()` is an aggregate function; it summarizes multiple rows. Without `GROUP BY` it will only generate one row. Try issuing this command to MySQL as you're learning to use `GROUP BY`, it will help you generate predictable results.  `SET SESSION sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `WHERE` clause. You are using `=` which means you are checking only for items  with a `required_date` 15 days in the future. Change the `=` to `<=`.

TIP: If you only want work orders from now to 15 days in the future, add another condition that only selects date after today: `Date(work_order_line_items.required_date) >= Curdate()`.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands now - its only looking at records where your date in the table matches 15 days from now.
You may want to try changing your Where clause to:

```
WHERE DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) between CURDATE() and DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

That should then give you a date range through the next 15 days.

You could also use >= and <=:

```
WHERE (DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) >= CURDATE()) AND (DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY))
```

These will get you the next 15 days, and preclude any data prior to today ( where as <= will give you everything including days in the past ).

Comment: i tried like this `SELECT bom.bid, bom.item, bom.cost, bom.location, work_order_line_items.id, work_order_line_items.item, DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) AS date, SUM(work_order_line_items.quantity) AS TQTY, items.item_id, items.in_stock FROM bom INNER JOIN work_order_line_items ON bom.item=work_order_line_items.item INNER JOIN items ON work_order_line_items.item=items.item_id WHERE (DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) >= CURDATE()) AND (DATE(work_order_line_items.required_date) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 DAY))`, but it gives only 1 record